# Why does the attached code below work on my Macbook's VS Code application but not on the VS Code app I run on the same device on Parallels Desktop?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, parallels

fairly new to python and I've managed to iron out any wrinkles I've overcome before. However, I'm stuck when it comes to this. I need to run a script I'm writing on Parallels Desktop since I cannot use the MetaTrader 5 python library on my Macbook's VS Code for an algo I'm writing.

The issue I've come across is that I need to run a certain section of the script once every 5th minute and so I am using the following code to trigger this.

```
import time

while True:
    if time.time() % (60 * 5) == 0:
        print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime(time.time())))  #code
```

I want triggered follows...

The code works with no issues on my Mac's VSCode but when I run it on Parallel's Desktop VScode, there is no output. No error either.

Is there any reason for this and how might I overcome this?

Thank you guys it's been eating at me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple sources why the code above code be problematic.
If you take a look at:

```
print(time.time())
#output
1677345971.6591382
```

Everything behind the decimal separator `.` is a very small proportion of a second (unit microsecond and below).

If you try `time.time() % (60 * 5) == 0` the chance of hitting a `time.time()` that looks like `1677345971.00000000` is minimal since your code wont be triggered at that exact microsecond.

But only in that case  `time.time() % (60 * 5) == 0` would be true since no microseconds are left in your modulus calculation.

I don't know why it works on your mac but i guess it is because your mac is not using float to show `time.time()`.

In your case you coult try to use the following code:

```
if int(time.time()) % (60 * 5) == 0:
```

This turns your time from `1677345971.6591382` into `1677345971` where the unit is seconds. Now your calculation `int(time.time()) % (60 * 5) == 0` can be fulfilled not only by chance of leaving 0 microseconds behind.

Comment: But this seems to have a flaw. It will repeat print many times in that second.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm experiencing. I've overcome this with a fix although it's not a great one:  while True:
    if round(time.time()) % (60 * 5) == 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('The time is', time.strftime('%H:%M', time.gmtime(time.time())))
        time.sleep(30)

Comment: Although I suppose I can use @tetris programming's solution and send the code to sleep for a bit so it doesn't trigger over and over again. This would be much simpler than my solution haha

Comment: Thank you very much @tetris programming!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think @tetris programming said the right thing about some inevitable mistakes in your code. However, it will repeat print() many times in that second.

I have provided the following code to help you better achieve your original purpose. Use the **schedule** package by command `pip install schedule`, which is a module for executing tasks on a regular basis.

```
import schedule
import time

def run():
    print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime(time.time())))  #code 

schedule.every(5).minutes.do(run)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: So I did try this initially but I realised that whilst this does run every 5 minutes, I need it to run on every fifth minute. So making this work would require me to time the while statement such that it is triggered on a fifth minute. Thank you very much though!!